# enforcePasswordHistory not working

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have an application which connect to a Active directory using Administrator profile. so when the password reset request is executed enforcePasswordHistory rule doesn't get applied.

[edited]
I need to have this rule applied because the password reset is done as part of account recovery.

Any idea on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Do you mean that you are *resetting* the password rather than changing it?  AFAIK password history doesn't apply to password resets.

Comment: I'm using password reset.
Is there any way that we can add that policy to administrator to work as well ?

Comment: I very much doubt it.